# HOw can I use ExternalInterface from my Flash AS2 swf in an iFrame to call a javascript method?

Tags: javascript, flash, iframe, actionscript-2, externalinterface

I have a PHP script which includes a header file (header.php) which includes a javascript file containing some javascript methods.

ie -

Main.php =>

```
include("header.php");
// This page also embeds a swf in an iFrame (myFlash.swf)
```

header.php =>

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript_methods.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

javascript_methods.js =>

```
myFunction() {
alert("function called");
}
```

myFlash.swf =>

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
//When I want to call the javascript function myFunction() -
ExternalInterface.call("myFunction");
```

I have used ExternalInterface elesewhere in my app and (think) i did it the same way but the only difference is this time the swf is inside an iFrame so think this might be causing the problem. Is there a solution to making this communication to javascript from Flash through an iFrame, or is this not the issue and I have a problem somewhere else.

thanks

Comment: What does the embed code look like? Can you post it please

Comment: Please remove everything PHP - it is only the _rendered_ HTML that is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The argument passed to `ExternalInterface.call` will be `eval`ed in the document where the flash is placed. This means that for this flash to reach the parent windows code, then it needs to do

```
ExternalInterface.call("window.parent.myFunction");
```